# What are some good armors Dark Souls 2

Tags: dark-souls-2

I am looking for some light armor in Dark Souls 2

Max weight I can carry so that I can still correctly perform the "fast roll" is 70%

I currently have Old Knight Greatsword equipped and the broadsword equipped.

Without any armor on, I am at 36%

Any recommendations and locations/seller names?

Thank you :)

Edit: For suggesting sets and researching and answering with it I'm +1 and whatever armor set I decide on using I'll accept by tomorrow

I need something protective, other attributes don't bother me but if you find an armor set that is < 70% that has bonus' then that'd be great

**Also it doesn't need to be a complete set from the same type, example: Elite Knight Helm, Elite Knight gloves, Elite Knight leggings, Elite Knight armor**

Comment: I think the question is still too broad, you need to narrow it down a bit since a "light" armor depends on many factors including your weight load, the amount of weapons you have equipped, etc. Maybe adding a "top weight" constraint.

Comment: I will edit in a moment
Fixed

Comment: I would try checking out [This link](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/armor) as there are tons of armor sets that are each good in their own respects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One fine example may be the Moon Butterfly Armor. This set is comprised of lightweight butterfly parts, and as such is not very protective, but it is capable of increasing your jumps and, best of all, poisoning your enemies. With this armor, you merely need to stand nearby your foe to begin poisoning them, causing the poison to buildup over time until they begin taking poison damage.

The set can be obtained in Majula either in NG+ or after burning a Bonfire Ascetic at the Far Fire, Majula. The armor becomes available from Maughlin the Armorer after spending a total of 16,000 souls in his shop. (Rest/travel after spending to update. BE WARY: Wearing the armor near friendly NPCs will poison them, making them hostile.

Also on the topic, another lightweight armor set can be obtained without the ascetic in a similar fashion, the Aurous set. The Aurous set can be obtained by exhausting Maughlin's dialogue after spending 16,000 souls in his shop WHILE holding 0 souls of your own. This can easily be done by falling to your death in Deep Pit, then talking to Maughlin to obtain the armor, and then retrieving your bloodstain. The Aurous set has better defense stats compared to the Moon Butterfly set, and each piece increases your max weight load.

Source: http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Moon_Butterfly_Set

Comment: Much appreciated:)
I'll allow people to keep offering other ideas though

Comment: Just like to add that you can use The Darksign item to lose your souls without dieing and losing your humanity.